# varnish param.set resets to previous value after service restart

Tags: caching, centos, varnish, rhel, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to fine tune varnish (4.0.4) with varnishadm (on RHEL).

I set the values with param.set, do param.show & everything looks ok.

But after I restart the varnish service the params are back to their previous values.

Is there a way to somehow save those & make them default (without somehow passing them to varnish every time after the service restart)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Open up `/etc/varnish/varnish.params` and add your params to `DAEMON_OPTIONS` like so:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-p cli_buffer=16384 -p another_parameter=value"
```

By default, the DAEMON_OPTS is commented, so make sure to remove the leading hash `#`.